# How many years have passed between the first season and the second episode of the second season in Fumetsu no anata e?

Tags: to-your-eternity

Between the first season, and the second episode of the season,,

> Fushi has met the granddaughter of Hayase, and the daughter of her, and the daugter of the daughter, and so on until he meets the first male descendant of Hayase who inherited her will.

How many years have passed between the first season and the second episode of the second season in Fumetsu no anata e?

Answer (score 1):

About 40 years as stated by the hisame, granddaughter of hayase in the first or second episodes. (not sure which one it was)